# Circle CI installs fail after making github repo private

Tags: node.js, github, continuous-integration, circleci-2.0

I've been using this setup for a while now and ever since I made my repo private my build fails on npm install. I added my github SSH keys to my Circle CI project as well as my config.yml file. Below is how things are organized.

Any help would be appreciated[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the repo you are using forked by chance? https://discuss.circleci.com/t/cannot-access-private-repository-from-free-tier/22600/6

Answer (score 0):

Remove the project from CircleCI, make sure CircleCI can "follow" private projects (you might have turned this off when you signed up) and then re-add the project.